# How to sort layered navigation attributes on Alphabetic order

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation

Trying to find a solution for the order of the attributes in layered navigation on the category list page.

Now I have to **sort** them in the attributes from backend, and it is not a good way with many entries.

How can I change the dropdown for the attributes to be sorted in `1-9` and `a-z` ? (not from backend)

Now it can be

```
B
P
8
A
```

When it should be

```
8
A
B
P
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will not give you the final solution but I will direct you to a place where you change the default behaviour.

So, if the attribute does not have a custom source it uses default source class which is `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table`. All of the attribute options are returned in a function `getAllOptions($withEmpty, $defaultValues)`. If you check it, you will find that in this function an `attributeOptionCollection` is created on which a function `setPositionOrder($dir, $sortAlpha)` is called. In this function we have hardcoded sort order of the options collection - `$this->setOrder('main_table.sort_order', $dir);`

I can give you quick 2 options to make it work as you want it:

- make a before plugin on `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::setPositionOrder` and change the `$sortAlpha` variable to `true` - I am not sure how the sorting will behave, but it should be alphabeticaly
- make and around/after plugin on `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::setPositionOrder` and change the sorting the way you want

There are of course more options, you can also make plugins for `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::getAllOptions` as well as you can override it (which I do not reccomend). Let me know which option you selected and good luck!

Comment: Thank you, $sortAlpha variable to true did the trick.

I might need to go deeper with the getAllOptions when I have added all the attributes. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Please be aware that this modification will probably sort the attribute options alphabeticaly everywhere on the site, if this is not a problem for you thank ok.

Comment: I tried the above. I have used before plugin. But not working. How can I return the value.

Comment: it's code not working it please help me how to specific attribute option filter by alphabetically

Comment: Which one is not working? Have you tried making plugins on getAllOptions()?

Comment: Wait, this is not an option in Magento admin...?!? 