# Magento 2 :Sort Attributes Alphabetically in layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, sort

I want to sort the attributes in layered navigation in the alphabetical order.

http://i.prntscr.com/zDuYTVDbSWqv_507ew0JbQ.png

Sort in the order as:Climate, Color, ...

I tried to override the setPositionOrder() in \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection using **before**.

Ref:[How to sort layered navigation attributes on Alphabetic order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247257/how-to-sort-layered-navigation-attributes-on-alphabetic-order)

My magento version is 2.3

But it didn't work. How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to override the filter.php file inside your child theme

app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/filter.php
and then add the following code

```
    <?php 
    $offsets = array();
    $offsets1 = array();
    $offsets2 = array();
    $offsets3 = array();
    foreach ($filterItems as $filters) {
        $checklable = $filters->getLabel();
        if(preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $checklable)){
            array_push($offsets1, $filters);
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/,/i", $checklable)){
            array_push($offsets2, $filters);
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/-/i", $checklable)){
            array_push($offsets2, $filters);
        }
        elseif(strstr($checklable, '/')){
            array_push($offsets2, $filters);
        }
        else{
            array_push($offsets3, $filters);
        }
    }
    asort($offsets1);
    asort($offsets2);
    sort($offsets3);
 
    $offsets = array_merge($offsets3,$offsets2,$offsets1);
?>
<ol class="items">
    <?php foreach ($offsets as $filterItem): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php //echo '===>'; ?>
            <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() > 0): ?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($filterItem->getUrl()) ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $filterItem->getLabel() ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
                        <span class="count"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $filterItem->getCount() ?><span class="filter-count-label">
                            <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?> <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('item') ?><?php else:?> <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
            <?php else:?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $filterItem->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
                    <span class="count"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $filterItem->getCount() ?><span class="filter-count-label">
                        <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('item') ?><?php else:?><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

this code is working for me

Answer (score 0):

For this,You need to override the **getList()** function in
**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Search/FilterableAttributeList.php**

Comment: it's code not working it please help me how to specific attribute option filter by alphabetically